# How do I add validation for a subform in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for options / best practices to solve my validation problem.

I have an  Asp.net MVC4 application using angular.js. My angular viewmodel has an object called Vendor. Vendor has an array of contacts called Contacts.

I want to allow the user to enter multiple contacts before they submit the form, but I also want validation on each contact. The user is required to add Name, Phone, Fax... etc. before they add the contact to the Contacts array. However, when they submit the entire form, I don't want the subform fields to invalidate the form.

I have looked into nested forms, but there doesn't seem to be a way of having separate form and subform scopes for the purpose of validation. In my case, the main form and subform fields need to be completely separate. (i.e. validate the subform when adding contacts, validate the main form when submitting the main form)

My current solution is to just add a custom validation routine on the ContactController addContact method.

Here is my code...

index.cshtml

```
<form role="form" name="Ctrl.vendorForm" data-ng-submit="vendorForm.$valid && Ctrl.updateVendor" id="vendor" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-controller="VendorController as Ctrl" novalidate>
...
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="#ContactsPanel" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">Contact Persons</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="ContactsPanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="pull-left" data-ng-repeat="contact in Ctrl.Vendor.Contacts">
                                <!-- use custom directives as Attributes (not Elements) to be IE8 friendly (IE9 issue??) -->
                                <div data-contact-card data-contact="contact" data-delete-contact="Ctrl.deleteContact(parmContact)"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
                            <!-- UI Bootstrap -->
                            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="Ctrl.shoMo()">Show me the Modal</button>-->

                            <div id="contactForm" data-ng-controller="ContactController as contactCtrl">
                                <h4>Create New Contact</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.FirstName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Enter first name..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.Last_Name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter last name..." />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.ContactEmail" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.Telephone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone number..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.ContactPhoneExtension" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone extension..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.ContactFax" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter fax number..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.ContactFaxExtension" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter fax extension..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.PrimaryContact" type="checkbox" /> Primary Contact<br/>
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.AcctReceivableContact" type="checkbox" /> Accounts Receivable Contact<br />
                                        <input data-ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.PurchaseOrderContact" type="checkbox" /> Purchase Order Contact<br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="submit" data-ng-click="contactCtrl.addContact(Ctrl.Vendor)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"  value="Save Contact" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
  <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Submit Form
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="SubmitPanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Code of Conduct</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input name="CodeOfConductAccepted" data-ng-model="Ctrl.Vendor.CodeOfConductAccepted" type="checkbox" required /> I have read and agree to accept the Code of Conduct.
                                    <p data-ng-show="vendorForm.CodeOfConductAccepted.$invalid" class="validation-message">You must accept the Code of Conduct before you can submit the form.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-ng-disabled="vendorForm.$invalid" value="Submit">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("vendorApp", [])

    app.controller('ContactController', function () {
        this.contact = {};
        this.counter = 0;

        this.addContact = function (Vendor) {
        if (_.isEmpty(this.contact.FirstName)) {
            alert("First Name is required");
            return;
        }
        if (_.isEmpty(this.contact.Last_Name)) {
            alert("Last Name is required");
            return;
        }
        if (_.isEmpty(this.contact.ContactEmail)) {
            alert("Email Address is required");
            return;
        }
        if (_.isEmpty(this.contact.Telephone)) {
            alert("Telephone is required");
            return;
        }
        if (this.contact.PrimaryContact || this.contact.AcctReceivableContact || this.contact.PurchaseOrderContact) {
            this.counter = this.counter + 1;
            this.contact.IsNew = true;
            this.contact.ClientID = this.counter;
            Vendor.Contacts.push(this.contact);
            this.contact = {};
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You must select a contact type.");
        }

    });

    app.directive('contactCard', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: '/Template/ContactCard',
            scope: {
                contact: '=',
                deleteContact: '&'
            }

        };
    });
}());
```

vendorCtrl.js

```
(function () {

    var vendorController = function (vendorService, $location, $modal) {
        var _this = this;

        this.getVendor = function (id) {
            vendorService.getVendor(id).success(function (data) {
                angular.extend(_this, data);
            })
        };

        this.deleteContact = function (contact) {

            if (contact.IsNew) {
                _.remove(_this.Vendor.Contacts, contact);
            }
            else {
                alert("Perform Server Side Delete");
            }
        };
    };

    vendorController.$inject = ['VendorService', '$location', '$modal'];
    angular.module("vendorApp")
    .controller('VendorController', vendorController);

}());
```

_ContactCard.cshtml

```
<div class="well">
    <input type="button" data-ng-click="deleteContact({parmContact: contact})" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"  value="X" />
    <strong>{{contact.FirstName}} {{contact.Last_Name}}</strong><br />
    <small>
        <i>
            <strong>
                <span data-ng-show="contact.PrimaryContact">Primary Contact<br /></span>
                <span data-ng-show="contact.AcctReceivableContact">Accounts Receivable Contact<br /></span>
                <span data-ng-show="contact.PurchaseOrderContact">Purchase Order Contact<br /></span>
            </strong>
        </i>
        Email: {{contact.ContactEmail}}<br />
        Phone: {{contact.Telephone}} <span data-ng-show="contact.ContactPhoneExtension.length">x{{contact.ContactPhoneExtension}}</span><br />
        Fax: {{contact.ContactFax}} <span data-ng-show="contact.ContactFaxExtension.length">x{{contact.ContactFaxExtension}}</span><br />
    </small>
</div>
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: Why does it matter if the overall form becomes invalid?

Comment: Have you looked into using `ngForm` within your `form`? [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

Comment: I ended up just adding custom validation checks in the ContactController method that adds the contact to the Vendor.Contacts array. (see app.js file)